# Selecionar valores no banco com comparação

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde Galera, estou com uma duvida
eu tenho uma base de dados com 2 campos  [ codPendAt e CodPend ]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso fazer um select aonde eu seleciono algumas pendencias e verifico se a anterior é algumas dessas que tenho se nao for nao exibe e se for exibe

**Essas sempre vai exibir na fila, independente da anterior:**

7.1, 7.4, 7.3, 7.2, 77.2, 77.7, 15.1, 15.2, 15.8, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3

```
SELECT * FROM agd.agd_agenda where codPend = '7.1' and codPend = '7.4' or codPend = '7.3' or codPend = '7.2' or codPend = '77.2' or codPend = '77.7' or codPend = '15.1' or codPend =  '15.2' or codPend = '15.8' or codPend = '2.1' or codPend = '2.2' or codPend = '2.37'
```

**Essas pendencias você somente vai exibir na fila se a anterior tiver sido alguma das que informei acima:**

3.1, 3.4, 3.7, 4.3, 4.15, 5.3, 5.4, 6.4, 6.5, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 14.8, 18.1, 18.3, 19.1, 19.2, 19.3, 19.4, 20.1

como eu faço essa verificação? como posso saber se mostro a 3.1 só se tiver alguma dessas de cima for a anterior no caso a tabela

**Só posso ixibir a (CodPen= 3.1) se a (CodPenAT for uma das de cima!)**

Eu tenho esse codigo rodando

```
$query .= " and (agd.isEntrada != 'S' and agd.codPend != '0'  and agd.codPend != '3.1' and agd.codPend != '6.3' and agd.codPend != '3.4' and agd.codPend != '3.7' and agd.codPend != '4.3' and agd.codPend != '4.15' and agd.codPend != '4.3' and agd.codPend != '6.10' and agd.codPend != '6.7' and agd.codPend != '7.1' and agd.codPend != '7.4' and agd.codPend != '77.2' and agd.codPend != '77.1' and agd.codPend != '77.7' and agd.codPend != '77.3' and agd.codPend != '6.2' and agd.codPend != '6.6'  and agd.codPend != '99.9' and agd.codPend not like '19.%' ) and ( agd.codPendAt in ('2.1', '7.3', '15.8', '2.2', '2.3', '2.1', '7.3', '15.1', '2.2', '2.3', '7.3', '15.7', '7.1', '7.4', '15.5', '15.6', '15.7', '15.2', '77.2', '77.7', '9.1', '9.3', '3.4', '5.3', '5.4') ) " ;
```

Precisava comparar antes de motrar a pendencia.

Agora como eu comparo elas? com os outros para pode exibir?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo exemplo que você mostrou, eu tenho uma tabela chamada agd_agenda e dois campos para consultar, que são codPend e codPendAt

Pelos critérios informados, teria que fazer duas consultas em separado e juntar os resultados

Consulta 1 - Os registros que sempre aparecem

```
SELECT * FROM agd.agd_agenda where codPend IN ('7.1', '7.4', '7.3', '7.2', '77.2', '77.7', '15.1', '15.2', '15.8', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3')
```

Consulta 2 - Os registros que são exibidos de forma condicional

```
SELECT * FROM agd.agd_agenda where agd.isEntrada != 'S' and codPend IN ('3.1', '3.4','3.7', '4.3', '4.15', '5.3', '5.4', '6.4', '6.5', '9.1', '9.2', '9.3', '14.8', '18.1', '18.3', '19.1', '19.2', '19.3', '19.4','20.1') AND codPendAt IN ('7.1', '7.4', '7.3', '7.2', '77.2', '77.7', '15.1', '15.2', '15.8', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3')
```

Para juntar resultados você pode utilizar o UNION, para isso as consultas devem retornar a mesma quantidade de campos, e a ordem dos campos deve ser igual, ou seja, os campos devem ter o mesmo tipo de dados.

Desta forma, a consulta unificada poderia ficar assim:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT <campos> FROM agd.agd_agenda where codPend IN ('7.1', '7.4', '7.3', '7.2', '77.2', '77.7', '15.1', '15.2', '15.8', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3')
UNION
SELECT <campos> FROM agd.agd_agenda where agd.isEntrada != 'S' and codPend IN ('3.1', '3.4','3.7', '4.3', '4.15', '5.3', '5.4', '6.4', '6.5', '9.1', '9.2', '9.3', '14.8', '18.1', '18.3', '19.1', '19.2', '19.3', '19.4','20.1') AND codPendAt IN ('7.1', '7.4', '7.3', '7.2', '77.2', '77.7', '15.1', '15.2', '15.8', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3')
) Tabela WHERE <condicoes> ORDER BY <condicoes>
```

Comment: Eu tentei, mais deu um erro

Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias /

Eu tirei essa parte -> Tabela WHERE <condicoes> ORDER BY <condicoes>